# How I get the text instead value from a select option in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, post

I have a form in which there is a select field with many options. These options have numeric values and a text between option tags. What I want to do is to get the text instead of values when I post the form via submit button.

View that generates the select field:

```
echo form_dropdown('pos', $pos_options, '100', 'id="pos_select" class="form_input"');
```

the select part generated:

```
<select name="pos" id="pos_select" class="form_input">
    <option value="0">about_history_title</option>
    <option vlaue="1">about_history</option>
</select>
```

When the form is submited, the appropriate model is called via the controller(text.php):

text.php -> insert_text()

```
$this->admin_text_model->insert_text();
```

admin_text_model.php

```
public function insert_text()
{
    $data = array(
        'tx_page' => $this->input->post('page'),
        'tx_pos' => $this->input->post('pos'),
        'tx_body' => $this->input->post('add_text')
    );

    return $this->db->insert('text', $data);
}
```

Is there a way that I can get the text inside option tags in $this->input->post('pos')?

Perhaps something like:

```
'tx_pos' => $this->input->post('pos')->text?
```

Comment: i think no there is no method to get like this you can set it in value and get

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot set the text as value

Comment: why dont you pass both the integer & text comma separated in value.. although it may not be recommended way

Comment: you can get text using javascript, use one hidden field and set its value as select box text and then submit the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this don't assign the value to option tag:

```
<select name="pos" id="pos_select" class="form_input">
    <option>about_history_title</option>
    <option>about_history</option>
</select>
```

It will return text of option.

Comment: what if the select option has records from database? like form_dropdown(), any idea?

Answer (score 4):

No, text inside `<option>` tags is never submitted. That is just how HTML works.

You must set the values, that you need to retrieve, in the `value` attribute. That is what they are for.

Comment: This is 100% incorrect and teaching readers non-sense.  If you want the text to be submitted, just omit the `value` attribute declaration from the option tags.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could make the select yourself and not using the CI helper. This way you have full control on what and where to output it:

   ```
   <select name="pos" id="pos_select" class="form_input">
     <?php foreach($pos_options as $option):?>
       <option value="<?php echo htmlentities($option);?>"><?php echo $option;?></option>
     <?php endforeach;?>
   </select>
   ```
2. **Or**, you could make an ugly hack in javascript:

   ```
   $('#pos_select option').each(function(){
      $(this).attr('value', $(this).text()); 
   });
   ```

Which sets the `value` of every option equal to its text content: http://jsfiddle.net/ursQY/

Comment: Why not `htmlentities()` the variable in both places?  You are writing dynamic data into an HTML document.